# Which function will fit this curve best?

Tags: statistics, functions

I am trying to do a test of normality on this 
[data set here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z3ku6c5hnemawfd/ani.csv?dl=0). My QQ Plot looks like this [image: QQPlot].

It looked like an arctan function to me. So my idea was to do a reverse "tan" function transformation on it. But first I need to find the exact function which will fit my data so that I can reverse it. And I am unable to do  that. Any ideas how should I proceed further?

Comment: Like one of these functions? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function

Comment: Is it this curve that you want to fit ?

Comment: If this is the curve you want to fit, give me a few points $(x,y)$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing the interpretation of the normal qq plot. A qq-plot generally is used to compare 2 probability distributions. In this case, to compare the distribution of your data to that of a normal distribution. The S shape you see in the graph means that your distribution is probably highly skewed or has heavier tails. Because of this, you should not use a model that assumes normality of the data. Maybe it is Poisson or some other skewed distribution?

This plot does **not** represent how a response variable behaves with respect to an independent cariable.

See this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%E2%80%93Q_plot